# No spacing between citations

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I'm trying to eliminate the space between the numbers in multiple citations, and I've tried using the `\usepackage[compress]{natbib}` and `\usepackage[nospace]{cite}` packages and commands to do it, but I get this error:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'. See the
biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for
immediate help.

... l.69 \begin

{document} The 'natbib' package and biblatex are incompatible.
```

I'm using `\documentclass[spanish,11pt,a4paper]{report}` and `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.
How can I work this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without a minimal example one can't be sure, but if you're using `biblatex` (and its default `numeric` style), don't try to load `natbib` or `cite` on top of it, but add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifuly! I've problems making the minimal examples because I can't really tell what is relevant and what it isn't.

Comment: @ariblogger that's actually the goal of a minimal example :) You should strip your file down as much as possible, then you often find out where the problem lies.